# ¿Existe algún reproductor responsivo de video para html5, que permita reproducir todos o la mayoría de los formatos?

Tags: jquery, html5, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, razor

Me gustaría saber si algún reproductor responsivo de video para html5, que permita reproducir todos o la mayoría de los formatos. He probado con uno que se llama Jplayer, pero solo acepta algunos formatos mp4, http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demos/

pero lo que ando buscando un reproductor en jquery o flash, o cualquier opcion buena, que sea responsivo, que permita reproducir cualquier video(mp4, avi, mpg, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los formatos admitidos por el navegador no dependen del reproductor que uses sino del propio soporte que le dan los navegadores a los formatos. Actualmente el mp4 es el más soportado con los codecs [H.264 y MP3](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4), ve el artículo [Formatos soportados por los navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) asi que por lo general lo que se hace es especificar varios formatos en el tag de [`video`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) para que se pueda hacer fallback en caso de que alguno de ellos no se pueda usar lo cual se puede hacer con el elemento [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)

```html
<video width="480" controls poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif">
    <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

Por lo general cuando no se soporta ninguno o no se tiene HTML5 lo que se hace es usar plugins para poder reproducir lo cual por lo general se hace con Flash y applets pero tiene la desventaja que si estos no están instalados no funcionará de todas formas.

Yo en lo personal he usado el plugin [video.js](http://videojs.com/) con muy buenos resultados porque te permite tener una experiencia uniforme entre navegadores incluso lo puedes instalar con bower

```
bower install --save video.js
```

Para usarlo se emplea un tag de video HTML5 igual que si fueras a usar la forma nativa

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.min.js"></script>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.gif" data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="https://archive.org/download/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
```

El video js se encarga de la reproducción y del look and feel del reproductor, el cual *es customizable y se ve identico en todos los navegadores!!!*.

También cuenta con una característica muy buena y es que soporta [plugins](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Plugins#plugins) así que si tienes alguna necesidad especial en la lógica de tu negocio puedes usar uno de los que ya estan o escribir el tuyo propio.

Comment: Si, pero si tengo un video en mi servidor, para que se pueda reproducir tendría que tener al menos 3 videos con 3 formatos distintos como alternativas, como el ejemplo que has puesto mp4, webm, ogg. Siendo asi, no sería tendría sentido estar llenando con videos alternativos, la idea es que si hay un formato, se lea. Además, a veces no siempre se ven los videos en MP4

Comment: Yo creo que es una excelente respuesta @devconcept. Danilo, te sugiero que le pidas a tu desarrollador que te ayude pasando los videos a esos formatos, al final es complicado tener un formato de video universal y esto es una buena opción.

Comment: @deconcept Que raro, el ultimo video de ejemplo no se me reproduce

Comment: @Danilo Como te expliqué en mi respuesta tienes que usar varios formatos si quieres cubrir la mayoría de los escenarios posibles. El soporte de video en HTML es un añadido reciente y como te expliqué anteriormente se hacia con Flash, si el usuario que navega tu página no lo tiene o es obsoleto quedas de todas formas como al principio. Si quieres la mejor experiencia tienes que sacrificar espacio, esa es la realidad. Recuerda que porque un video tenga extensión MP4 no significa que este codificado con los codecs correctos especificados para video y audio.

Answer (score 3):

A raíz de los comentarios del autor de la pregunta, sugiero lo siguiente:

Recién acabo de terminar un RWD con fondo de pantalla de video (Background Fullsreen HTML5), de ello aprendí lo siguiente lo cual comparto mis anotaciones.

Cada navegador reproduce video HTML5 a su manera y va a depender de la antigüedad del navegador y el [códec](http://www.encoding.com/resources/#HTML5) instalado en el dispositivo del navegante. A más viejo el navegador es peor la reproducción. El orden de los formatos de videos que se desea presentar es importante y dependerá de la calidad de video que se tenga. Aquí un código para inserción de video en HTML5:

```
<div id="fullscreen-bg">
    <video id="bg-video" autoplay poster="images/home-video-poster.jpg" loop>
        <source src="videos/home-intro.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="videos/home-intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="videos/home-intro.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
        <source src="www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bGNuRtlqAQ" type="video/3gpp" />
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="videos/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;">
            <param name="movie" value="videos/flashfox.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=true&amp;poster=images/home-video-poster.jpg&amp;src=videos/home-intro.m4v" />
            <embed src="videos/flashfox.swf" width="1280" height="720" style="position:relative;" flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=true&amp;poster=images/home-video-poster.jpg&amp;src=videos/home-intro.m4v" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
            <img alt="Video playback is not supported by your browser" src="images/home-video-poster.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0px;width:100%;" title="Video playback is not supported by your browser" />
        </object>
    </video>
</div>
```

Para un diseño web adaptable (RWD), tendría que usar tu destreza en programación o ayudarte con plugins externos tales como [EasyHTML5Video](http://easyhtml5video.com/es/).

Aquí te muestro el soporte de los navegadores según codec:

[image: Formatos admisibles para equipos Desktop]
[image: Formatos admisibles para equipos Móviles]

Sin embargo; a pesar que hagamos mucho esfuerzo para dar lo mejor al visitante, al final podrías darte cuenta que sería mejor subir el video a YouTube y desde ahí reproducir a través de su [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es).Ya que el reproductor de YouTube servirá el video según características del navegador del usuario, ya sea por tamaño de la pantalla, diámetro, codex, resolución, etc.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'ab0TSkLe-E0',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Para no escribir mucho código, puedes ayudarte con [Media Element](http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube) escribiendo solo esto:

```
<video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
<source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI" />
```

Creo que te estoy dando información suficiente para que te ayude en tu proyecto. Lo de RWD es diseño, usa CSS2.1+ con HTML5+

Saludos