# como puedo hacer un reproductor para leer archivos m3u8 que funcione para mobil

Tags: html, video-adaptativo, hls

tengo dias buscando un reproductor para archivos m3u8, actualmente tengo este codigo que uso para mis canales

```html
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/ejuoyqCsEeK4ayIACpYGxA.js"></script>
<script>// <![CDATA[
jwplayer.key="6RfMdMqZkkH88h026pcTaaEtxNCWrhiF6ACoxKXjjiI=";
// ]]&gt;</script>
<div id="playerOPr7jp5Kixy0_wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 700px; height: 400px;"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/8/jwplayer.flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="playerOPr7jp5Kixy0" name="playerOPr7jp5Kixy0" tabindex="0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"></object><div id="playerOPr7jp5Kixy0_aspect" style="display: none;"></div><div id="playerOPr7jp5Kixy0_jwpsrv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div></div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
jwplayer('playerOPr7jp5Kixy0').setup({
    file: "http://a3live-lh.akamaihd.net/i/antena3_1@35248/master.m3u8",
    width: "700",
    skin: "five",
    height: "400",
    title: 'xsoundtv.com',
    image: "",
    logo: {
    file: "",
    position: 'top-right',
    margin: '0',
    link: ""
    },
    stretching: "fill",
    autostart: "true",
                abouttext: '',
            aboutlink: '',
  });
// ]]&gt;</script>
```

pero no funciona en teléfonos mobil, que debo hacer para que funciones, gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que debes hecharle un vistazo a http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4889/existe-alg%C3%BAn-reproductor-responsivo-de-video-para-html5-que-permita-reproducir/4890#4890

Comment: Al ejecutar su código genera el siguiente error `The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag`. Comprueba si el archivo puede ser accedido y/o que el archivo esté dañado. Añade mas información acerca de que si este código genera errores.

Comment: @Mauricio recuerda que los stack-snippets corren en un `iframe` y estos tienen un atributo `sandbox` para establecer permisos de como se ejecutará el contenido interno. Debes copiar el ejemplo para una página local y ejecutarlo desde ahi. Saludos.

Comment: hola a todos gracias por responder miren aquí el código de arriba funcionando http://palmiracorre.blogspot.com.co/2016/07/cdatajwplayer.html

Comment: he encontrado uno buscando por la internet, el codigo es este: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.clappr.io/latest/clappr.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clappr.rtmp/latest/rtmp.min.js"></script>
<div id="player">&nbsp;</div>
<script>
        var player = new Clappr.Player({
            source: "http://a3live-lh.akamaihd.net/i/antena3_1@35248/master.m3u8",
            parentId: "#player",
   width: '730px',
   height: '450px',
            autoPlay: true,
            
            
        });
      </script>

Comment: gracias me sirvió de mucho, se te agradece por compartir el contenido del reproductor, sos un genio