# Como leer al archivo video que he guardado en mi base de datos mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, rutas, stream, fstream

Estoy intentando guardar una coleccion dentro de mongodb (Lesson) donde entre otros datos esta coleccion lleva un video:

**Lesson Model**

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var LessonSchema = Schema({

    title: String,
    creator: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    course: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Course'},
    video: String,
    description: String,
    created_at: String

 });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Lesson', LessonSchema);
```

El siguiente paso seria salvar esa coleccion en base de datos, esta es la manera en la que lo he hecho:

**LessonController**

```
function saveLesson(req, res){

var params = req.body;
var lesson = new Lesson();

if (params.title && params.description && params.course) {

    lesson.title = params.title;
    lesson.creator = req.user.sub;
    lesson.course = params.course;
    lesson.video = null;
    lesson.description = params.description;
    lesson.created_at = moment().unix();

    Lesson.find({ $or: [{title: lesson.title}, {description: lesson.description}] }).exec((err, lessons) =>{

        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Petition failed'});

        if (lessons && lessons.length >=1) {

            return res.status(500).send({message: 'The lesson already exist'});

        }else{

            lesson.save((err, lessonStored) =>{

                if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Petition failed'});

                if(!lessonStored) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The lesson can`t be save'});

                return res.status(200).send({ lesson: lessonStored});
            });            
        }
    });

}else {
    return res.status(500).send({message: 'Please complete the require   fields'});
  }
}
```

Una vez que salvo la lesson en base de datos lo que intento hacer es actualizarla subiendole un archivo de video, como se puede ver en el siguiente codigo, donde hasta aqui todo va bien:

**Upload the video of the lesson**

```
function uploadVideo(req, res){

var lessonId = req.params.id;
if (req.files) {

    var file_path = req.files.video.path;
    var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
    var file_name = file_split[3];
    var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
    var file_ext = ext_split[1];

    Lesson.findById(lessonId, (err, lesson)=>{

        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Petition failed!'});

        if (!lesson) return res.status(404).send({message: 'There is not lesson to update'});

        if (lesson.creator._id != req.user.sub) {
            return removeFileOfLoad(res, file_path, 'Sorry, you don`t have permition to update the data of the current lesson');
        }else{

            if (file_ext == 'avi' || file_ext == 'mp4' || file_ext == 'mkv' || file_ext == 'mpg') {

                Lesson.findByIdAndUpdate(lessonId, {video: file_name}, {new: true}, (err, lessonUpdated) =>{

                    if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Petition failed'});

                    if (!lessonUpdated) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The current lesson can not be update'});

                    return res.status(200).send({lesson: lessonUpdated});
                });
            }else{
                return removeFileOfLoad(res, file_path, 'The extention is not valid!');
            }
        }
    });
}else{

    return res.status(200).send({message: 'Please select a video for the current lesson'});
   }
}

function removeFileOfLoad(res, file_path, message) {

  fs.unlink(file_path, (err)=>{
      return res.status(200).send({message: message});
  }); 
}
```

Todo lo antes implementado va bien hasta que intento obtener el archivo de video para leerlo en el navegador de la siguiente manera

**Get video lesson by file_path**

```
function getVideoFile(req, res){

var video_file = req.params.videoFile;
var file_path = './uploads/lessons/videos/'+video_file;

fs.exists(file_path, (exists) => {

    if (exists) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(file_path));
        // var rs = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
        // res.rs;
    }else{
        res.status(200).send({message: 'There is not video lesson'});
      }
   });
}
```

Finalmente mi problema es que no puedo leer el video tal y como quisiera hacerlo, darle play, pause en fin por leer el video. He intentado tal y como he hecho con las lineas que estan comentadas en el codigo de obtener el video por el file_path, pero no me funciona... Alguien podria decirme si hay una mejor solucion de implementar dicha funcionalidad que la que he tratado de exponerles aca?.. Saludos y gracias ....por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En node el request y el response son streams, un [Readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) y un [Writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams) respectivamente. Tu puedes hacer un [Readable](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream) con tu fichero y hacerle `pipe` en tu response. La solución es tan complicada como esto

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./path/to/my/file');
readStream.pipe(res);
```

Te quedaría así

```
function getVideoFile(req, res){
    const video_file = req.params.videoFile;
    const file_path = './uploads/lessons/videos/'+video_file;

    try {
        const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file_path);
        readStream.pipe(res);
    } catch(e) {
        res.status(200).send({message: 'There is not video lesson'});
    }
}
```

Lo bueno de usar streams es que hacen un uso óptimo de la memoria. Los streams usan pequeños buffers para ir enviando la información a medida que se lee teniendo sólo en memoria el pedazo que se está leyendo actualmente.

Deberías considerar usar status codes para cuando no hay video, usar un [`404`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) le indica al front-end que el video no se encontró.

Comment: Gracias, he probado como me has dicho y ha funcionado, lo que queda ya es el problema del navegador imagino para que lea videos en formato .mp4 por que he cargado video en .webm y asi si me funciona todo. thanks..

Comment: @AryanGarcia Lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4889/existe-alg%c3%ban-reproductor-responsivo-de-video-para-html5-que-permita-reproducir/4890#4890. Asegurate de usar los codecs correctos.